# Probability space proof

Tags: probability, measure-theory

---

**PROBLEM**

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $(E_n)$ be a sequence in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$.

$a)$ If the sequence $(E_n)$ is increasing (in the sence that $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$) with limit $E = \cup_nE_n$, prove that $P(E_n) \rightarrow P(E)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$b)$ If the sequence $(E_n)$ is decreasing with limit $E$, prove that $P(E_n) \rightarrow P(E_n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

---

**MY APPROACH**

$a)$ We know that $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$ so obviously $E_{n+1}$ consists of all sequences $E_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

$b)$ We know that the sequence is decreasing so $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$, so $E_1$ consists of all sequences $E_i$ for $ 2 \leq i \leq n$

---

I don't know how to formulate these proofs properly. I hope someone could help me..

Comment: The axiom of a probability measures involve a disjoint sequence. In the case a), do you see a transformation of $(E_n)$ into a sequence of disjoint sets whose union is $E$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you, so maybe for example the sequence $\{E_i - E_{i-1}\}_{i=1}^n$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Ok thank you, so how can this help me?

Comment: There are some typos: a limit over $n$ of something cannot depend on $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Define $A_n:=E_{n}\setminus E_{n-1}$:  and $A_0:=E_0$. Then

- if $i\neq j$, we have $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$;
- for each $N$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^NA_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^NE_i$;
- $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^NA_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb P(A_i)$.

b) Consider the sequence $(\Omega\setminus E_n)_n$. This forms a non-decreasing sequence, hence using the result of the first part: 
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty(\Omega\setminus E_N)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n(\Omega\setminus E_j)\right).$$
The LHS is $1-\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty E_n\right)$ while the RHS is $1-\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^nE_j\right)$.

Comment: For (b), can't you just define $E=\bigcap_{i=1}^nE_i$, so that $P(E)=P(\bigcap_{i=1}^nE_i)=P(E_n)$, where the last equality follows since $E_n$ is the smallest set among the $n$ sets?

Comment: DavideGiraudo, What do you think? And if not, how else would you do it?

Comment: Your $E$ seems to depend on $n$. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but if you look at question a, then there E also depends on $n$. Do you think it's correct. And else, can you show me your solution?

Comment: The OP probably meant that $\mathbb P(E_n)\to\mathbb P(E)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Can you please explain the solution to $(b)$ because I can't get it?

Comment: @901301 I edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I do not really see what you are doing, how is the left part equal to $P(E_n)$ and the right part to $P(E)$?

Comment: I've edited again, there was problem with the indexes. I've also added details.